# Post request works in Postman but does not work in JavaScript program using node-fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman, fetch-api

I am trying to make a post request to the Sakai LMS API. I am trying to login.

---

What I have in Postman here works **perfectly fine**, it hits the endpoint and returns the session id. The API seems to use **Form Data** to accept data.

[image: Screenshot from Postman client]

So as you can see it **successfully** hits the login endpoint and returns everything needed within the header.

**Now I would like to implement this in a JavaScript program using node-fetch.**

---

Here is what I have done:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
var FormData = require('form-data')

class login {

    constructor() {
        var formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('eid', 'exampleUsername')
        formData.append('pw', 'examplePassword')
        var url = "https://examplelogin/portal/xlogin"

        console.log(formData)
        
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        })
            .then(r => r)
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data.headers) 
            })
    }
}
```

---

This currently **does not** return as a successful login, it returns some data within the Headers but not the session id which is needed to proceed.

I feel as if this could be an Authentication problem where the Postman client identifies itself as a client where the JavaScript program does not.

Can anyone identify what might be the problem here?

Comment: Can you try to add the necessary headers to the options param, here's a shorthand: ```{
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData,
  headers: formData.getHeaders()
}```

Comment: @MAS Hi there. I tried that earlier after looking at the node-fetch docs. It seems to not change anything unfortunately

Comment: Hi! At least I got to inspect Postman's request and compare it with the one fired from nodejs!
Also worth mentioning that in form-data [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data#axios), they state the following >  // In Node.js environment you need to set boundary in the header field 'Content-Type' by calling method `getHeaders`. So it must be mandatory! Now let's try to manipulate the headers again which I've managed to pull the most important ones..

Comment: ```const formHeaders = {
  ...formData.getHeaders(),
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0',
  'Content-Length': formData.getLengthSync(),
  'Host': 'www.tutorialrepublic.com'
};``` replace the Host with the one you're sending to, without http or anything just the domain.
Now if you try to POST to this demo [URL](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/examples/php/display-comment.php) it will work and returns 200 success!!

Comment: @MAS Also, may I ask how you are inspecting the requests from Postman and Node? I would like to do this with the Python request as this seems to work flawlessly for what I am trying to do

Comment: @MAS Thanks very much for the help, I have implemented what you have posted there and I am now getting an error: "FetchError: request to https:/<SITEHERE>/portal/xlogin failed, reason: socket hang up when using HTTPS, when using HTTP I get the same response as before :(.. Btw the post request in Python works just fine, I posted about it here if you wish to see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60804880/trying-to-recreate-a-python-api-call-request-in-javascript-using-fetch-with-form

Comment: LOL they don't wanna deal with us anymore! no clue what's happening!
Anyway, here is a straight to the point [guide](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/capturing-http-requests/) for Postman. For nodejs, I just mount a middleware at the very beginning of app.js/server.js for all requests ```app.use('*')``` and then I spam logs in there as much as the use-case require. But some use-cases require a very specific details or to generate some reports, so I end up sniffing TCP traffic using [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/)! More than welcome :)

Comment: @MAS Hey so I've found a way to make it work within my Javascript program. So I copied the headers from the Python requests.post call (the request headers) and pasted them in the headers of the node-fetch call. It seems to work. The thing that is making it all work is the JSESSIONID cookie which needs to be present in the POST request header. I do not understand how the JSESSIONID Cookie ends up in the header of the POST request? I looked at the console of Postman and it seems to do a POST request first, then a GET request. I am not understanding how it obtains the Cookie.

Comment: This is totally makes sense now, this turned to be a Tomcat server authentication related issue after all. But as far as I know, authentication errors are loud and clear, the whole web is using **401** status code! But we had no clue about it because it looks like it's a bad server implementation from their side! Btw, were you authenticated on Postman? did you try to login and obtain a cookie from there?! Check [this](http://datum-bits.blogspot.com/2012/02/setting-jsessionid-cookie-in.html) out, last paragraph they explains what to do if the client wasn't a browser. See the code there line 5?

Comment: We wouldn't come-up with that even after a million year. a random cookie key, with even a random encoded value! Also see [this](https://serverfault.com/a/927489) the guy sums it all. Anyway glad it worked man, if I ever come across into this problem again, I will just copy all of the headers I can find on the internet and paste then into the damned HTTP request!! :D